# MacBook Pro- wifi connected but no internet after unplugging ethernet

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, ethernet

I recently set up my modem/router through xfinity, and after activation I unplugged the Ethernet cord to try to connect my laptop to wifi. My phone is connected and working well but my laptop won't go online even though it's showing that it's connected to my network. I spent over an hour on the phone with Comcast troubleshooting, and we determined it has something to do with my computer. The computer was connecting to other networks just fine before I plugged in the Ethernet cable (it was the first time it ever had one plugged in) but now won't work on any wifi network including ones it had previously worked on. Help!!!

Comment: Check your wifi settings. DHCP should probably be set to auto, DNS empty (or with greyed out numbers provided by your ISP, or you can try 8.8.8.8 + 8.8.4.4), and your IP should be in the same range your wifi is if connected to the same network (most of the time).

Comment: Check in Network System Preferences.  What interfaces show in the left-hand column, and in what order?  You should have Wi-Fi listed first, with a green dot.  If Wi-Fi is not listed first, then it's trying to connect some other way, and failing, so you need to rearrange the service order.

Answer (score 1):

Boot the computer to Recovery (hold Command and R on restart) and ensure it connected to your WiFi network. Then select Get Help Online. This actually loads a file stored in Recovery, so type in a URL and see if it loads. If it does not, your computer is not the issue.

Comment: Boot to recovery? Will I lose any files or anything?

Comment: No, recovery contains a set of utilities, one of which is Safari - listed in the menu as "Get Help Online". Another is a means to reinstall the operating system, but I'm not proposing you do that.